# loop a PRINT 3 times FOR each TIME it PRINT one word FROM this 3 PRINT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want TO loop a PRINT 3 times FOR each TIME it PRINT one word FROM this 3 SELECT

```
PRINT I'm mark  

PRINT HI
PRINT hello
PRINT how are you
```

I try this

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 0

PRINT 'Im mark' 
WHILE @i < 1
BEGIN
PRINT 'hi' 
SET @i = @i + 1
END 
PRINT '-------------------'
SET @i = 0
PRINT 'Im mark' 
WHILE @i < 1
BEGIN
PRINT 'hello' 
SET @i = @i + 1
END 
PRINT '-------------------'
SET @i = 0
PRINT 'Im mark' 
WHILE @i < 1
BEGIN
PRINT 'how are you' 
SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

but it loop all the block 3 time I want the result to be like this
I want a loop it just a simple exemple my work is big

```
-----loop I------
I'm mark  
Hi

-----loop II------
I'm mark  
hello

-----loop III------
I'm mark 
how are you
```

Comment: This is not easy to understand. Please provide sample input and output so we can better understand your needs.

Comment: Why do you need a loop? You could use a `UNION ALL` to concat the rows, although i really don't understand the requirement.

Comment: I update my question I just want to loop the word (I'm mark) 3 time for every time it print hi or hello or how are you like I said

Comment: Is [I'm mark] in one table and [HI], [hello] and [how are you] in anotber table? I don't understand what you meant by "3 SELECT"

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #test(id int,col varchar(50));
insert into #test values(1,'HI');
insert into #test values(2,'hello');
insert into #test values(3,'how are you');


declare @msg varchar(50);
declare @i int;
declare @msgTemp varchar(50);

set @msg='I m Mark' + CHAR(13); -- Char(13) is the New Line character in TSQL
set @i=1;

while(@i<4)
      begin
        print @msg

        select @msgTemp=col
        from #test where id=@i

        print @msgTemp + CHAR(13)

        set @i=@i+1;
      end

Drop table #test
```